# How can i get babel highlighting in sublime 3?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, package, babeljs

How can i get code inside

```
<script type="text/babel">
```

highlighted ? I have Babel package installed ... Seems it works when i putting JS code into .jsx file and including to project, but how get it works in .html file ?

Comment: https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime/issues/228

Comment: @KeithHall Thank you. And how can i check if i disable stock JS and what JS is running now?